# Making it more effective (New to python)

Tags: python

Im new to coding and made this thing.
How can i make it more efficient? I'd like to store it in a file and have some more information about every level but i can't get my head around that.

And if i want say 100 levels, what would be the best way then?

```
level = input("What is your level? ")

if level == '1':
  salary = 5
elif level == '2':
  salary = 5.5
elif level == '3':
  salary = 6.05
elif level == '4':
  salary = 6.65
elif level == '5':
  salary = 7.32
elif level == '6':
  salary = 8.05
elif level == '7':
  salary = 8.85
elif level == '8':
  salary = 9.74
elif level == '9':
  salary = 10.71
elif level == '10':
  salary = 11.78

print(salary)
```

Comment: Use a dictionary (dict) object.

Comment: Write a json and load it using json.load(...) and use that for lookup

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that the formula is `5 * 1.1 ** (level-1)` rounded down to 2 digits after the point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the salary corresponds to the second decimal floor value  of the function `salary = 5 * (1 + 0.1)**(level - 1)`.

I did this working example for you:

```py
level = input('What is your level?')
try:
    level = int(level)
    if level < 1 or level > 10:
        raise ValueError()
except ValueError:
    raise ValueError('You must give a positive not null number <= 10.')

salary = 5 * 1.1**(level - 1)
floored_salary = int(salary * 100) / 100
print(floored_salary)
```

Results:

```py
for level in range(1,11):
    salary = 5 * 1.1**(level - 1)
    print(f'{level=}, salary={int(salary * 100) / 100}')
---
level=1, salary=5.0
level=2, salary=5.5
level=3, salary=6.05
level=4, salary=6.65
level=5, salary=7.32
level=6, salary=8.05
level=7, salary=8.85
level=8, salary=9.74
level=9, salary=10.71
level=10, salary=11.78
```

Answer (score 0):

Use type dict :

```
level = int(input("What is your level? "))
Dict = {
     1:5,
     2:5.5,
     3:6.05,
     4:6.65,
     5:7.32,
     6:8.05,
     7:8.85,
     8:9.74,
     9:10.71,
     10:11.78,
     }
salary=Dict.get(level)
print(salary)
```

Comment: What if `level` is not in `Dict`?

Comment: `salary=Dict.get(level,'not defined')` would be a solution, and it would probably be better to keep `level` as a string if doing so.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax is also new to Python (3.10 onwards);

```
level = input("What is your level? ")

match level:
    case '1':
        salary = 5
    case '2':
        salary = 5.5
    case '3':
        salary = 6.05
    case '4':
        salary = 6.65
    case '5':
        salary = 7.32
    case '6':
        salary = 8.05
    case '7':
        salary = 8.85
    case '8':
        salary = 9.74
    case '9':
        salary = 10.71
    case '10':
        salary = 11.78
    case _:
        salary = 'undefined'
print(salary)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some workarounds to @[ErnestBidouille](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12158123/ernestbidouille) great solution:

```
rate = list(map(lambda i: round(5 * (1 + 0.1)**(i - 1), 2), range(1, 101)))
level = int(input("What is your level? "))
salary = rate[level-1]
print(salary)
```

Or:

```
rate = list(map(lambda i: round(5 * (1 + 0.1)**(i - 1), 2), range(1, 101)))
while True:
    try:
        level = int(input("What is your level? "))
        salary = rate[level-1]
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Numbers only')
    except IndexError:
        print('No level found')

print(salary)
```